# lua - How to check if a word is in a string or it is just a word

Tags: lua

So I am trying to make a language in lua, and I am replacing the word "output" with "print" and a few more words, but if someone does output("output") it also replaces it. How can i check if it is in a string?
Code:

```
output('trying to make a new language in lua')
output('\n')
local file = io.open(arg[1],"r")
local code = file:read "*a"
local filename = arg[1]
local function execute()
    code = code:gsub("output","print")
  code = code:gsub("void","function")
  code = code:gsub("{}}","end")
  local newfile = io.open(filename:gsub("idk","lua"),"w")
  newfile:write(code)
  newfile:close()
  os.execute("lua test.lua")
end
execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

Lua patterns are generally unsuitable to build a parser for a programming language; neither do they have the full expressive power of regular expressions required for tokenization (lexical analysis) nor do they get anywhere near the power of a context-free grammar (CFG, syntactical analysis) required for constructing the abstract syntax tree even though they provide some advanced features such as bracket matching which exceed regular expression capabilities.

As a beginner, you'll probably want to start with a handwritten tokenizer; as your language only operates at a token replacement level at this stage, you can simply replace identifier tokens.

You don't need string replacement (`gsub`) to implement variable renames like `print` to `output` when you are in control of how the script is executed: Just replace the global `print` variable with an `output` variable holding the `print` function (you may want to do this only in the environment the scripts written in your language run in):

```lua
output = print
print = nil
```

Comment: See also [ltokenp](https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#ltokenp)